# How can I prevent pages from rendering unnecessarily when using Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

When I run my code, the Main page and the Component_A page render at first. Then when I press the button and increase or decrease the count, only page A renders. B page does not render. But when I go to the Component_B page, when I press the button there, both Component_A and Component_B page render.How can I render only the page I am using?

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './context/reducer';
import initialState from './context/store';
import {Component_A, Componenet_B} from './components';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Main = () => {
  console.log('renderMain');
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="A" component={Component_A} />
          <Stack.Screen name="B" component={Componenet_B} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

**Component_A.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const Component_A = ({navigation}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const myCounter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  console.log('renderA');

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#eceff1', flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Component_A</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>Counter:{myCounter}</Text>
      <Button title="Go to B" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('B')} />
      <Button title="Increase" onPress={() => dispatch({type: 'Increase'})} />
      <Button title="Decrease" onPress={() => dispatch({type: 'Decrease'})} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Component_A;
```

**Component_B.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const Componenet_B = ({navigation}) => {
  const {counter} = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log('renderB');

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#bdbdbd', flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Componenet_B</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>{counter}</Text>
      <Button title="Go to A" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('A')} />
      <Button title="Increase" onPress={() => dispatch({type: 'Increase'})} />
      <Button title="Decrease" onPress={() => dispatch({type: 'Decrease'})} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Componenet_B;
```

**reducer.js**

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Increase':
      state.counter = state.counter + 1;
      return {...state};
    case 'Decrease':
      state.counter = state.counter - 1;
      return {...state};

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0,
};
export default initialState;
enter code here
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your reducer would work I'd stick to the [immutable update patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Increase':
      return { ...state, counter: state.couner + 1 };
    case 'Decrease':
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

If you do `const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);` then the component will only render when counter changes. But instead of passing an anonymous arrow function to useSelector I'd use [reselect](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) selector functions instead so both component A and B can re use the same selector function.

Comment: Although I was working, I couldn't how to use the reselect package. Could you help with the code?

Comment: @nigranac You could try the [link](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) in my answer. I tried to document how I use it with React and you can have a look at the example code. The point of reselect is that you can re use selectors for other selectors so you don't implement the same logic multiple times. You also get memoization that could make your app perform better as it won't re render or recalculate if values didn't change.

Comment: I wonder if I understood correctly according to the code I wrote?
import {createSelector} from 'reselect';

selector.js
export const newCounter = createSelector(
  (state) => state.counter,
  (counter) => {
    console.log('counter has worked');
    return counter;
  },
);


OtherA.js
const myCounter = useSelector(newCounter);

Comment: @nigranac Your counter can be `const selectCouner = state => state.counter` A reselect selector is when you want to select multiple things or calculate something. Say I have many counters then I can do `const selectCounters = state => state.counters` and use reselect to reuse selectCounters and calculate total: `const selectTotal = createSelector(
  [selectCounters],
  (counters) => counters.reduce((c, total) => total + c, 0)
);`

Comment: Got it :)Thank you